# Determine SQL configuration VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a simple way to determine the SQL memory allocation weather its express or full version and if its 2005/ 2008 and so on?
I am fairly new to vb.net so any information or code samples would be great I know about the SQL Server Operating System Related Dynamic Management Views but am not sure how to use them to get the information i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a long string of all the attributes of the current sql install with this:

```sql
SELECT @@VERSION
```

or you can break it down with this:

```sql
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

Here is a sample of VB to help:

```vb
        Dim tempResult As String

    Using tempConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("{yourConnectionString}")
        Using tempCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
            tempCommand.CommandText = "SELECT @@VERSION"
            tempCommand.Connection = tempConnection
            tempResult = CStr(tempCommand.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've added `<-- language: sql -->` to your answer, so the code formatter does the right thing (it was displaying the code as VB)

Comment: This is something like i am looking for except this application is going to run on different servers so i wont always have the connection string in code.

Comment: Are you asking how/where to store the connection string info?  Just do a search for that.  That has been answered hundreds of times with many different answers depending on your needs.  Hard coding it is certainly not an optimum location, but works for sample code.